# FPDF WriteHTML() multiple table render showing only first one correctly

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

I am using [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) to render tables which are inside the html contents.
So as I wanted to render tables I got this [link](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script50.php) to render the table. The thing is I have two tables one after another in the html and I can't make it separate as because the content is coming through `WYSIWYG` editor. Here for the first table its working fine. But for the second table it is not working at all. I have checked all the markup and everything looks good.

html_table.php is like this

```
    <?php
//Based on HTML2PDF by Clément Lavoillotte


require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
require('htmlparser.inc.php');

class PDF_HTML_Table extends FPDF
{
var $B;
var $I;
var $U;
var $HREF;

function PDF($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $format='A4')
{
    //Call parent constructor
    $this->FPDF($orientation,$unit,$format);
    //Initialization
    $this->B=0;
    $this->I=0;
    $this->U=0;
    $this->HREF='';
}

function WriteHTML2($html)
{
    //HTML parser
    $html=str_replace("\n",' ',$html);
    $a=preg_split('/<(.*)>/U',$html,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    foreach($a as $i=>$e)
    {
        if($i%2==0)
        {
            //Text
            if($this->HREF)
                $this->PutLink($this->HREF,$e);
            else
                $this->Write(5,$e);
        }
        else
        {
            //Tag
            if($e[0]=='/')
                $this->CloseTag(strtoupper(substr($e,1)));
            else
            {
                //Extract attributes
                $a2=explode(' ',$e);
                $tag=strtoupper(array_shift($a2));
                $attr=array();
                foreach($a2 as $v)
                {
                    if(preg_match('/([^=]*)=["\']?([^"\']*)/',$v,$a3))
                        $attr[strtoupper($a3[1])]=$a3[2];
                }
                $this->OpenTag($tag,$attr);
            }
        }
    }
}

function OpenTag($tag, $attr)
{
    //Opening tag
    if($tag=='B' || $tag=='I' || $tag=='U')
        $this->SetStyle($tag,true);
    if($tag=='A')
        $this->HREF=$attr['HREF'];
    if($tag=='BR')
        $this->Ln(5);
    if($tag=='P')
        $this->Ln(10);
}

function CloseTag($tag)
{
    //Closing tag
    if($tag=='B' || $tag=='I' || $tag=='U')
        $this->SetStyle($tag,false);
    if($tag=='A')
        $this->HREF='';
    if($tag=='P')
        $this->Ln(10);
}

function SetStyle($tag, $enable)
{
    //Modify style and select corresponding font
    $this->$tag+=($enable ? 1 : -1);
    $style='';
    foreach(array('B','I','U') as $s)
        if($this->$s>0)
            $style.=$s;
    $this->SetFont('',$style);
}

function PutLink($URL, $txt)
{
    //Put a hyperlink
    $this->SetTextColor(0,0,255);
    $this->SetStyle('U',true);
    $this->Write(5,$txt,$URL);
    $this->SetStyle('U',false);
    $this->SetTextColor(0);
}

function WriteTable($data, $w)
{
    $this->SetLineWidth(.3);
    $this->SetFillColor(255,255,255);
    $this->SetTextColor(0);
    $this->SetFont('');
    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        $nb=0;
        for($i=0;$i<count($row);$i++)
            $nb=max($nb,$this->NbLines($w[$i],trim($row[$i])));
        $h=5*$nb;
        $this->CheckPageBreak($h);
        for($i=0;$i<count($row);$i++)
        {
            $x=$this->GetX();
            $y=$this->GetY();
            $this->Rect($x,$y,$w[$i],$h);
            $this->MultiCell($w[$i],5,trim($row[$i]),0,'C');
            //Put the position to the right of the cell
            $this->SetXY($x+$w[$i],$y);                    
        }
        $this->Ln($h);

    }
}

function NbLines($w, $txt)
{
    //Computes the number of lines a MultiCell of width w will take
    $cw=&$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
    if($w==0)
        $w=$this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
    $wmax=($w-2*$this->cMargin)*1000/$this->FontSize;
    $s=str_replace("\r",'',$txt);
    $nb=strlen($s);
    if($nb>0 && $s[$nb-1]=="\n")
        $nb--;
    $sep=-1;
    $i=0;
    $j=0;
    $l=0;
    $nl=1;
    while($i<$nb)
    {
        $c=$s[$i];
        if($c=="\n")
        {
            $i++;
            $sep=-1;
            $j=$i;
            $l=0;
            $nl++;
            continue;
        }
        if($c==' ')
            $sep=$i;
        $l+=$cw[$c];
        if($l>$wmax)
        {
            if($sep==-1)
            {
                if($i==$j)
                    $i++;
            }
            else
                $i=$sep+1;
            $sep=-1;
            $j=$i;
            $l=0;
            $nl++;
        }
        else
            $i++;
    }
    return $nl;
}

function CheckPageBreak($h)
{
    //If the height h would cause an overflow, add a new page immediately
    if($this->GetY()+$h>$this->PageBreakTrigger)
        $this->AddPage($this->CurOrientation);
}

function ReplaceHTML($html)
{
    $html = str_replace( '<li>', "\n<br> - " , $html );
    $html = str_replace( '<LI>', "\n - " , $html );
    $html = str_replace( '</ul>', "\n\n" , $html );
    $html = str_replace( '<strong>', "<b>" , $html );
    $html = str_replace( '</strong>', "</b>" , $html );
    $html = str_replace( '&#160;', "\n" , $html );
    $html = str_replace( '&nbsp;', " " , $html );
    $html = str_replace( '&quot;', "\"" , $html ); 
    $html = str_replace( '&#39;', "'" , $html );
    return $html;
}

function ParseTable($Table)
{
    $_var='';
    $htmlText = $Table;
    $parser = new HtmlParser ($htmlText);
    while ($parser->parse())
    {
        if(strtolower($parser->iNodeName)=='table')
        {
            if($parser->iNodeType == NODE_TYPE_ENDELEMENT)
                $_var .='/::';
            else
                $_var .='::';
        }

        if(strtolower($parser->iNodeName)=='tr')
        {
            if($parser->iNodeType == NODE_TYPE_ENDELEMENT)
                $_var .='!-:'; //opening row
            else
                $_var .=':-!'; //closing row
        }
        if(strtolower($parser->iNodeName)=='td' && $parser->iNodeType == NODE_TYPE_ENDELEMENT)
        {
            $_var .='#,#';
        }
        if ($parser->iNodeName=='Text' && isset($parser->iNodeValue))
        {
            $_var .= $parser->iNodeValue;
        }
    }
    $elems = explode(':-!',str_replace('/','',str_replace('::','',str_replace('!-:','',$_var)))); //opening row
    foreach($elems as $key=>$value)
    {
        if(trim($value)!='')
        {
            $elems2 = explode('#,#',$value);
            array_pop($elems2);
            $data[] = $elems2;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}

function WriteHTML($html)
{
    $html = $this->ReplaceHTML($html);
    //Search for a table
    $start = strpos(strtolower($html),'<table');
    $end = strpos(strtolower($html),'</table');
    if($start!==false && $end!==false)
    {
        $this->WriteHTML2(substr($html,0,$start).'<BR>');

        $tableVar = substr($html,$start,$end-$start);
        $tableData = $this->ParseTable($tableVar);
        for($i=1;$i<=count($tableData[0]);$i++)
        {
            if($this->CurOrientation=='L')
                $w[] = abs(120/(count($tableData[0])-1))+24;
            else
                $w[] = abs(120/(count($tableData[0])-1))+5;
        }
        $this->WriteTable($tableData,$w);

        $this->WriteHTML2(substr($html,$end+8,strlen($html)-1).'<BR>');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->WriteHTML2($html);
    }
}

}
```

and the index.php is like this

```
<?php
require('html_table.php');

$pdf = new PDF_HTML_Table();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);

$html='<table border="1">
<tr>
<td width="200" height="30">cell 1</td><td width="200" height="30" bgcolor="#D0D0FF">cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="200" height="30">cell 3</td><td width="200" height="30">cell 4</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td width="200" height="30">cell 5</td><td width="200" height="30" bgcolor="#D0D0FF">cell 6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="200" height="30">cell 7</td><td width="200" height="30">cell 8</td>
</tr>
</table>
';

$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Can someone tell me how to solve this issue? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HTML code to build tables for PDF documents generated with the FPDF library, then have a look at the FPDF easyTable project https://github.com/fpdf-easytable/fpdf-easytable

```
$table=new easyTable($pdf, 3, 'border:1;');

// first row
$table->easyCell('Text 1', 'valign:T'); 
$table->easyCell('Text 2', 'bgcolor:#b3ccff;');
$table->easyCell('Text 3');
$table->printRow();

//second row
$table->rowStyle('min-height:20; align:{C}'); 
$table->easyCell('Text 4', 'colspan:3');
$table->printRow();

$table->endTable(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem the other day, and came up with the following solution:

1. In your FPDF class, add a function `findAll()`. This will be used to find all instances of `<table` and `</table` in your HTML to convert:

   ```
   function findAll($needle, $haystack) 
   {
     // initialize the return value array
     $rv = array();

     // set up a temp variable to make things simple
     $temp = 0;

     // successively find each instance of needle in haystack
     while($temp < strlen($haystack)) 
     {
       $temp = strpos($haystack,$needle, $temp);

       if($temp !== false) 
       {
         $rv[] = $temp;
         $temp++;
       } 
       else
       {
         // nothing to find
         return $rv;
       }
     }

     return $rv;
   }
   ```
2. Modify your `WriteHTML()` function to a) use `findAll()` to find all table instances, and b) replace each one (keeping any non-table formatting intact). This modification essentially "chunks" your HTML into "table" and "non-table" pieces, and formats the HTML accordingly:

   ```
     function WriteHTML($html)
     {
       $w = array();

       // search for a table
       $starts = $this->findAll('<table',strtolower($html));
       $ends = $this->findAll('</table',strtolower($html));

       if(count($starts) > 0 && count($ends) > 0)
       {
         $positions[0] = 'doc-start';

         foreach($starts as $key => $start)
         {
           $end = $ends[$key];
           $positions[$start] = 'table-start';
           $positions[$end] = 'table-end';
         }

         $endPos = strlen($html)-1;
         $positions[$endPos] = 'doc-end';

         $lastKnownPos = 0;

         for($q=1;$q<=$endPos;$q++)
         {
           if(isset($positions[$q]))
           {
             $curPos = $positions[$q];

             if($curPos == 'table-start')
             {
               $this->WriteHTML2(substr($html,$lastKnownPos,$q-$lastKnownPos).'<BR>'); 
               $lastKnownPos = $q;
             }
             else if($curPos == 'table-end')
             {
               $tableVar = substr($html,$lastKnownPos,$q-$lastKnownPos+8);
               $tableData = $this->ParseTable($tableVar);

               for($i=0;$i<count($tableData[0]);$i++)
               {
                 if($this->CurOrientation=='L')
                 {
                   $w[$i] = abs(277/(count($tableData[0])));
                 }
                 else
                 {
                   $w[$i] = abs(190/(count($tableData[0])));
                 }
               }
               $this->WriteTable($tableData,$w);
               $lastKnownPos = $q+8;
             }
             else if($curPos == 'doc-end')
             {
               $this->WriteHTML2(substr($html,$lastKnownPos,$q-$lastKnownPos).'<BR>'); 
               $lastKnownPos = $q;              
             }
           }
         }
       } 
       else
       {
         // if there is no table, just write the HTML as normal
         $this->WriteHTML2($html);
       }
     }
   ```